# EditText Method invocation may produce java.lang.NullpointerException

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

First and foremost , I have read the questions with the same title as mine here;

So please go through the question once. I am developing an application that takes values from a shared preference file and puts those values in `EditText` fields, for this I have used `setText()` method. I keep getting this warning in android studio. I realize this is just a warning , but I would like to know

1. What causes this?
2. How to rectify this?

Code is as follows:

```
    EditText sil_key = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.silent_key);
    EditText gen_key = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.general_key);
    EditText vib_key = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.vibrate_key);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key),MODE_PRIVATE);
    sil_key.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("silent","silent"));
    gen_key.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("general","general"));
    vib_key.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("vibrate","vibrate"));
```

And lastly I get the same warning with `getText()` used with `EditText`;Why? and How to rectify?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [editText.getText() may produce NullPointerException](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093090/edittext-gettext-may-produce-nullpointerexception)

Comment: Just a heads up. Studio has a "contract" system. If a function CAN return null, then, one possible value on that variable is null. Then, if you are requesting an operation on a variable that CAN be null, then the warning appears, the same will happen, should you use a function that returns boolean, on a variable that cannot hold it, or do an operation on a variable that was not initialized etc... those warnings are a single "contract -> event" system, that aids developers on common small mistakes.

Comment: @Ironman The question you tagged doesn't have an answer, I had seen it before posting this question

Comment: @Bonatti Thank you, but is there any way around this?

Comment: Yes. You can ensure that the contract is valid (such as `if(sil_key!=null){...stuffs...}`) or remove the warning signs with `@SuppressWarnings("The warning type")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare EditText in class level and then initialize further in onCreate(). this would solve your problem.

```
class Test extends AppCompactActivity{

private EditText sil_key;

onCreate(){

...

sil_key = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.silent_key);

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.preference_file_key),MODE_PRIVATE);
    sil_key.setText(sharedPreferences.getString("silent","silent"));

...
    }
 }
```

You can refer to this link as answer given by @Rod_Algonquin. it gives you a reason for this.

[EditText.setText() Null Pointer Exception](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25416743/edittext-settext-null-pointer-exception)

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a duplicate as if you read some answers such as [here (as linked by @Ironman)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23093090/edittext-gettext-may-produce-nullpointerexception). The warning states

> This is no error, it is just a warning. The static analyzer cannot deduce that your EditText or the result from EditText.getText() isn't null. The keyword here is 'may'.
>
> Adding a (possibly unnecessary) null-check for both instances will make the warning disappear.

As Answered by @nhaarman in the linked question.

Comment: I have seen that question and I have stated it in my question that it was a warning not an error, I wanted to know how to get past that

Comment: It has already been understood it's not an error or a warning. The quote in my answer specifically tells you how to avoid that warning. `Adding a (possibly unnecessary) null-check for both instances will make the warning disappear.`

Comment: It's ok, the answer I accepted is working well. By the way, how should I add a null-check? Use if(isNull), something like that?